# Cannot read property 'toString' , 'isNan' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, electron, undefined

I have been getting this error repeatedly and I haven't been able to find the exact cause for this.
The error is:

```
Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined
    at Calculator.appendNumber (calc.js:16)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (calc.js:96)
```

This is happening with `toString` as well as `isNan`

Here is my HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="calc.css">
    <title>Calculator</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="calculator_grid">
        <div class="output">
            <div data-previous-operand class="previous_operand"></div>
            <div data-current-operand class="current_operand"></div>
        </div>
        <button data-all-clear class="span_two">AC</button>
        <button data-delete >Del</button>
        <button data-operation>/</button>
        <button data-number>1</button>
        <button data-number>2</button>
        <button data-number>3</button>
        <button data-operation>*</button>
        <button data-number>4</button>
        <button data-number>5</button>
        <button data-number>6</button>
        <button data-operation>+</button>
        <button data-number>7</button>
        <button data-number>8</button>
        <button data-number>9</button>
        <button data-operation>-</button>
        <button data-number>.</button>
        <button data-number>0</button>
        <button data-equals class="span_two">=</button>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="calc.js">
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my Javascript:

```
class Calculator {
    constructor(previousOperandTextElement, currentOperandTextElement) {
        this.previousOperandTextElement = previousOperandTextElement
        this.currentOperandTextElement = currentOperandTextElement
    }
    clear(){
        this.currentOperand = ''
        this.previousOperand = ''
        this.operation = undefined
    }
    delete(){
      this.currentOperand =  this.currentOperand.toString().slice(0, -1)
    }
    appendNumber(number){
        if (number === '.' && this.currentOperand.includes('.')) return
    this.currentOperand = this.currentOperand.toString() + number.toString()
    }
    chooseOperation(operation){
        if (this.currentOperand === '') return
        if (this.previousOperand !== ''){
            this.compute()
        }
      this.operation = operation
      this.previousOperand = this.currentOperand
      this.currentOperand = ''

    }
    compute(){
     let computation
     const prev = parseFloat(this.previousOperand)
     const current = parseFloat(this.currentOperand)
     if(isNan(prev) || isNaN(curent)) return
     switch(this.operation){
         case '+':
             computation = prev + current
             break
        case '-':
             computation = prev - current
             break
        case '/':
             computation = prev / current
             break
        case '*':
             computation = prev * current
             break
            default:
                 return
     }
     this.currentOperand = computation
     this.operation = undefined
     this.previousOperand = ''
    }

    getDisplayNumber(number) {
        const stringNumber = number.toString()
        const integerDigits = parseFloat(stringNumber.split('.')[0])
        const decimalDigits = (stringNumber.split('.')[1])
        let integerDisplay
        if (isNan(integerDigits)) {
            integerDisplay = ''
        } else {
          integerDisplay = integerDigits.toLocaleString('en',{ maximumFractionDigits: 0})
        }
        if(decimalDigits != null){
            return `${intgerDisplay}.${decimalDigits}`
        } else {
            return integerDisplay
        }
    }

    updateDisplay(){
    this.currentOperandTextElement.innerText = this.getDisplayNumber(currentOperand)
    if (this.operation != null ) {
            this.previousOperandTextElement.innerText = 
         `${this.getDisplayNumber(this.previousOperand)} ${this.operation}`
      } else {
          this.previousOperandTextElement.innerText = ''
      }
    }

}


    const numberButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-number]')
    const operationButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-operation]')
    const equalsButton = document.querySelector('[data-equals]')
    const deleteButton = document.querySelector('[data-delete]')
    const allClearButton = document.querySelector('[data-all-clear]')
    const previousOperandTextElement = document.querySelector('[data-previous-operand]')
    const currentOperandTextElement = document.querySelector('[data-current-operand]')
    const previousOperand = document.querySelector('[data-previous-operand]')
    const currentOperand = document.querySelector('[data-current-operand]')

    const calculator = new Calculator (previousOperandTextElement, currentOperandTextElement)
    
    numberButtons.forEach(button =>{
        button.addEventListener('click', () =>{
        calculator.appendNumber(button.innerText)
        calculator.updateDisplay()
        })
    })

    operationButtons.forEach(button =>{
        button.addEventListener('click', () =>{
        calculator.chooseOperation(button.innerText)
        calculator.updateDisplay()
        })
    })

    equalsButton.addEventListener('click', button => {
      calculator.compute()
      calculator.updateDisplay()  
    })

    allClearButton.addEventListener('click', button => {
      calculator.clear()
      calculator.updateDisplay()  
    })

    deleteButton.addEventListener('click', button => {
      calculator.delete()
      calculator.updateDisplay()  
    })
```

I am using Electron and any help resolving this issue will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It seems like `button.innerText` is undefined.

Comment: You use `isNan()` and `isNaN()`. The function is called `isNaN()` so `isNan()` obviously is undefined ... Furthermore you have a typo in `isNaN(curent)` because the variable is called `current` Maybe you should use an IDE for developing. This would have highlighted all of these errors ...

Comment: @derpirscher am using Visual studio code actually are there any good plugins for it that can help with finding small errors like this? Because no errors where shown on there

Comment: @Aplet123 how would I go about giving it a relevant value? Should I just declare it somewhere else and leave it blank?

Answer (score 0):

plese add checks with `calculator.appendNumber(button.innerText)` like this

```
button && button.innerText && calculator.appendNumber(button.innerText)
```

Comment: Where would I use this check?